# Сборка приложения C++ с Vmime

Tags: c++, email

Пишу приложение для отправки почты. Посоветовали использовать библиотеку Vmime.
Приложение состоит из единственного main.cpp, в котором я даже особо ничего и не написал:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vmime/vmime.hpp>
#include <vmime/text.hpp>
#include <vmime/platforms/posix/posixHandler.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vmime::platform::setHandler vmime::platforms::posix::posixHandler>();

    vmime::messageBuilder mb;
    mb.setSubject (vmime::text(string("Message subject").c_str()));

    return 0;
}
```

Для генерации Makefile использую Cmake. Содержимое CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set (PROJECT Mail)

project (${PROJECT})

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11")

set (HEADER
)

set (SOURCE
    main.cpp
)

add_executable ( ${PROJECT} ${HEADER} ${SOURCE} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} vmime)
```

Эта программа уже не собирается. Ошибка:
main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `vmime::text::text(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Если это поможет: я недавно "сильно" обновил g++, чтобы попробовать C++11. До обновления эта программа работала. Какая была версия, я не помню, но сейчас стоит 5.3.0.

Comment: Возможно вам необходимо библиотека Vmime собранная C++11

Comment: Пересобрал.Что ж, куда-то продвинулось... Теперь другие ошибки возникли:
‘make_shared’ is not a member of ‘vmime’ и 
‘shared_ptr’ is not a member of ‘vmime’

Comment: @AccumPlus добавьте `std::` перед `shared_ptr` и `make_shared`. И убедитесь, что подключен заголовочник `<memory>`.

Comment: Теперь новая ошибка:
no matching function for call to ‘vmime::addressList::appendAddress(std::shared_ptr<vmime::mailbox>)’

Comment: Видимо конфликт пространства имён. Если вы добавляли std, то сделали это не во всех местах. Хотя может быть для Vmime собранной C++11, необходимы свои хидеры?

Comment: Согласно документации: since November 2013, we switched from an old, intrusive implementation of smart pointers to a more standard one:   either Boost shared ptr<> implementation or standard C++ one if we are compiling in C++11. На самом деле, я не уверен, что я в тему написал, но скорее всего это как-то связано

Comment: @Unick а про хидеры ничего не сказано

Comment: @AccumPlus Видимо какой-то конфликт между C++11 shared_ptr и их собственными. Может быть стоит найти нужные настройки компиляции.

Comment: @Unick скорее всего да. Вчера попробовал собрать эту программу на домашнем компе... Выводы такие. Vmime нужно собирать именно тот, который на github у них лежит (там сборка через Cmake). Предыдущие версии почему-то мне давали такой конфликт. Но для новой версии нужны современные версии многих библиотек, в частности gtk+ > 3. На рабочем сервере у меня Centos 6.x - ему, к сожалению, не видать эту версию. Так что пошёл через libcurl - вполне доволен.